# How do I programmatically create a GUI and create it for my windows form?

Tags: winforms

As above, how do I create buttons or labels programmatically instead of using the drag and drop function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create button during runtime in C#.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943152/create-button-during-runtime-in-c-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sample is a code for creating a panel.

```
    public Panel createPanel()
    {
        Panel p = new Panel
        {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Size = new Size(506, 110),
            Name = "Panel"
        };

        Button button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Clear",
            Name = "Button",
            Location = new Point(410, 40)                
        };

        p.Controls.Add(button);
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `YourForm.Designer.cs` and see how it's done.

Remember that they're just object members.

Comment: How would this help, if you're not using Visual Studio?

Comment: @FabioPoloni It's C#. chances are you're using Visual Studio. That's what's usually used for C# development. Microsoft created a nice IDE for their language

Comment: I came along this question because I'm not using Visual Studio. But yes, you're right.